# Limit of a sequence by epsilon delta definition

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $p(x)= ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$
Show that $$lim p(n+1)/p(n)$$ is 1.
By using epsilon delta definition of limit of sequence.
My attempt:
$$\frac{p(n+1)-p(n)}{p(n)}=\frac{3an^2+(3a+2b)n + (a+b+c)}{an^3+bn^2+cn+d}$$
What should I do next?

Comment: @Ravi: $x$or $n$ tend to what?

Comment: n tend to infinity

Comment: @Thomas Shellby. Sorry I forgot. I've edited the que.

Comment: I found an example that can help you. It is by definition proof. see this:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1238451/prove-lim-limits-n-to-infty-fracn215n2n1-frac15-directly-f/1238482#1238482

Comment: @Khosrotash: I checked it. But that question contains the real numbers directly so we can apply order properties easily to conclude next inequalities. But here my actual problem is there are real numbers a,b,c,d about them the only info given is a is no non zero (since it is a leading term). And nothing else. How to proceed here?

Comment: I write some idea below. please take a look

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{ n \to \infty} \frac{3an^2+(3a+2b)n + (a+b+c)}{an^3+bn^2+cn+d}=0\\
\forall \epsilon >0 \exists n \in \mathbb{N}: |\frac{3an^2+(3a+2b)n + (a+b+c)}{an^3+bn^2+cn+d}-0|<\epsilon$$ now work on epsilon

$$|\frac{3an^2+(3a+2b)n + (a+b+c)}{an^3+bn^2+cn+d}|<\epsilon$$you must find an upper bound for $\frac{3an^2+(3a+2b)n + (a+b+c)}{an^3+bn^2+cn+d}$ and take it less than $\epsilon$
for big enoug $n$ we have $$3an^2+(3a+2b)n + (a+b+c)<4an^2\\
an^3+bn^2+cn+d >\frac12 an^3$$ so we can rewrite as below
$$|\frac{3an^2+(3a+2b)n + (a+b+c)}{an^3+bn^2+cn+d}|\leq |\frac{4an^2}{an^3+bn^2+cn+d}|\leq |\frac{4an^2}{\frac12an^3}|=\frac 8n<\epsilon$$ 
can you take over now.

you can choose more upper bound (for sure) such as $\frac{9}{n},\frac{10}{n},...$